# Javascript recursion not working

Tags: jquery, recursion, minesweeper

**I'm making a jquery minesweeper** and am currently working on the revealing function for when you click a block with `0` adjacent mines. The intended result is to loop through all 8 adjacent blocks reveal those blocks, if they are also '`0`' blocks, it recurs for that block:

```
function reveal(block) {
    block.removeClass('hide');
    var thex = getXY(block)[0];
    var they = getXY(block)[1];
    if (blockNumber(block) == '0') {
        alert('test');
        --they;
        --thex;
        var nearmines = 0;
        for (mody=0;mody<3;mody++){
            for (modx=0;modx<3;modx++){
                var newx = thex + modx;
                var newy = they + mody;
                reveal(bl(newx,newy));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Currently this function** is stopping after the first block checked for each time the function iterates. It seems as though the call is breaking the `for loops`.

Comment: maybe you have to declare the mody and modx variables inside the reveal function. I don't know what happends if you use it this way.. is it a global variable?

Comment: Sure would help if we know what functions bl(x,y) and blockNumber(no) were. I can only assume that getXY returns [x,y] array (instead of using block.x & block.y...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have an infinite recursion - both directly and indirectly. Calling `reveal(bl(2,2))` will call `reveal(bl(2,2))` in the loop. In addition, if  `bl(1,2)` is also `0`, it will also call `reveal(bl(2,2))` when searching for each neighbor.

You should check for the "base case" in the first line:

```
if(!block.hasClass('hide'))
    return;
```

Comment: @Korvin - no problem! It wasn't more than an educated guess though `:)`